# Migrating from Seam 2 to Seam 3

Tags: seam, seam2, seam3

I have some experience with seam 2, and now I am trying seam 3, but I notice there are a lot of differences.

I would like to know if there is some kind of tutorial or blog post to read for someone who is migrating from seam 2 to seam 3, like me. I already found http://seamframework.org/Seam3/Seam2ToSeam3MigrationNotes, but that is way too short...

regards...

Answer (score 1):

Migrating from seam 2 to seam 3 is very painfull process in most cases worth no effort. Firstly you must find someone, who does not know that it is impossible thing and then pray that he will not notice this.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no migration guide yet. The Seam team is working on it.